# What is the escape character for % in python's string method

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a string which has a '%' in it (its actually a sql query string). How do I pass the % (do I have to use a specific escape character?

eg:
compute_answertime("%how do I%")

Comment: Instead of string formatting, use the sql parameterized queries. They'll do a better job at preventing injection than anything you can do yourself. For sqlite, see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute)

Answer (score 4):

Use another `%` to escape it

```
>>> compute_answertime("%%how do I%%")
```

Answer (score 1):

use %%..........

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
%%; DROP TABLE Students; --
```

Sorry, [couldn't resist](http://xkcd.com/327/).